# Linear Regression through Origin - What is the formula to find the error of the slope in y=ax

Tags: regression

[image]

How do we find the standard error of the slope of a linear regression through the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the usual linear model (for which $\hat{\beta} = \frac{\sum_iX_iY_i}{\sum_iX_i^2}$ is the least square estimate):
$$Y_i = X_i\beta + \varepsilon_i$$
 where $\varepsilon_i$ are centred i.i.d. random variables.

You can write that $\hat\beta = \beta + \frac{\sum_{i}X_i \varepsilon_i}{\sum_iX_i^2}$
and so $\mathrm{var}(\hat\beta) = \frac{\sum_i X_i^2\sigma^2}{(\sum_i X_i)^2} = \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum_i X_i^2}$ where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the $\varepsilon_i$.

Now, if you want an estimate of $\sigma^2$ (as $\sigma^2$ is usually unknown), you can use $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_i{(\hat y_i - y_i)^2}$ where $\hat y_i = x_i\hat{\beta}$.

So now you have an estimate of the variance of $\hat\beta$ : $\hat{\mathrm{var}}(\hat\beta)= \frac{\hat\sigma^2}{\sum_i{X_i^2}}$ .

Comment: Although the method is correct, the algebra fails at the point where you omit the square from $X_i$ in the denominator.  Because the ultimate answer is correct, that's likely only a typographical error.  If you elect to fix this, it would be nice to have an explanation of the "$n-1$" in the denominator of $\hat \sigma^2.$  (It's a little different than the usual explanation -- this is an instance of $n-p$ where there are $p$ linearly independent explanatory variables.)